# Port forwarding: docker -> vagrant -> host

Tags: networking, docker, ftp, vagrant, portforwarding

I have a docker machine with ftp service running into a vagrant machine, the vagrant machine is running into a macos host. The docker machine ftp service is accessible from vagrant machine via `ftp localhost`, but how can I expose it to the mac host?. The Mac -> Vagrant network is NATS, so I made a port forwarding like 21:21 between Mac host and Vagrant but, at host, I make `ftp localhost` and it doesn't work. :'( what am I doing wrong?

This is part of the output of `ps aux` in the vagrant machine:

`root      7841  0.0  0.5 113612  8948 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1108 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1108
root      7849  0.0  0.6 121808 10176 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1107 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1107
root      7857  0.0  0.7 154592 11212 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1106 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1106
root      7869  0.0  0.7 154592 12212 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1105 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1105
root      7881  0.0  0.6 113612 10172 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1104 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1104
root      7888  0.0  0.7 162788 11192 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1103 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1103
root      7901  0.0  0.6 121808 10156 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1102 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1102
root      7909  0.0  0.6 154592  9216 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1101 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1101
root      7921  0.0  0.5 121808  9196 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 1100 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 1100
root      7929  0.0  0.7 162788 12244 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 21 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 21
root      7942  0.0  0.5 121808  8936 ?        Sl   12:35   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 20 -container-ip 172.17.0.1 -container-port 20
message+  7961  0.0  0.3 111224  5248 ?        Ss   12:35   0:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)`